# Fabrik form submission issue, getting JSON response instead of thank you page

Tags: php, forms, joomla

I have a Joomla site 2.5.4 and contact form is build using Fabrik plugin. When I submit the contact form I receive a JSON response instead of thank you page.

I have set the form properly from the back-end as well. Please refer image below for details of back-end setup.

[image]

Please check JSON response below

```
{
msg: "Record added/updated",
url: "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=24",
baseRedirect: false,
rowid: "0",
redirect_how: "newpage",
width: 300,
height: 300,
x_offset: 0,
y_offset: 0,
title: "",
reset_form: true
}
```

Comment: On contact form submission , I get above json response and the process stucks. No thank you page is displayed as desired.

Comment: Check if the JavaScript is included AND WORKING!

Comment: Which version of Fabrik do you use ?

Comment: Sorted now, thnx guys. I have created a new form now.

Comment: @SashantPardeshi consider answering this question yourself if you solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

i had something similar with telerik returning results as json instead of actual page, no solution was possible so i just recreated the same telerik element again and it works now.

try creating the element from scratch and compare the difference between previous and current version, to note the issue.

Answer (score -1):

i do not know much about joomla.but here is a thing your json should be in below format

```
{
"msg": "Record added/updated",
"url": "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=24",
"baseRedirect": false,
"rowid": "0",
"redirect_how": "newpage",
"width": 300,
"height": 300,
"x_offset": 0,
"y_offset": 0,
"title": "",
"reset_form": true
}
```

your key of json should also be in double quotes.